# How to copy superclass properties to a subclass?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

Let's say I have two Classes like so:

```
Car
{
   NSInteger wheels;
   NSInteger bumpers;
}

+ (Car *)carWithData:(NSDictionary *)carData;


Lexus : Car
{
   GPS *navigation;
}

+ (Lexus *)carWithData:(NSDictionary *)carData;
```

`carWithData:` is a simple helper method that creates an instance of `Car` populated with variables from `carData`. Lexus' version would also set the `navigation` data.

How would Lexus' `carWithData` look like without duplicating code from `Car`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is accomplished by calling `super`'s implementation of `init…` in the init method:

```
//Car.m:
- (id)initWithData:(NSDictionary *)carData {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        //setup generic car properties:
        self.wheels = [carData objectForKey:@"wheels"]; //example
        self.bumpers = [carData objectForKey:@"bumpers"]; //example
    }
    return self;
}

+ (id)carWithData:(NSDictionary *)carData {
    return [[[self alloc] initWithData:carData] autorelease];
}


//Lexus.m:
- (id)initWithData:(NSDictionary *)carData {
    //this call to super is where the car's generic properties get initialized:
    self = [super initWithWithData:carData];
    if (self) {
        //setup lexus car properties:
        self.navigation = [carData objectForKey:@"navigation"]; //example
    }
    return self;
}

//there is no need to override super's [carWithData:] method as it's only a wrapper anyway.
```

Also note that both the `initWith…` and `carWith…` methods return `id`, not `Car` or `Lexus`.
The way your code is set up you end up with casting problems, where `[Lexus carWithData:dataDict]` does return an object of class `Lexus`, but the compiler doesn't know about it, as it expects a `Car`.

Comment: Ah, I didn't know you can actually do `[self alloc]` inside a Class method. I think this answer might be the cleanest.

Comment: @pixelfreak: Sure you can. Unlike C++, or the like, there are no limits in Objective-C regarding class method calls.

Comment: @pixelfreak: In Objective-C `self` refers to the **instance object** when in **instance methods** and to the **class object** when in **class methods**. (Remember that in Objective-C classes are actually objects themselves.)

Comment: @pixelfreak: You're welcome! Now go and kill all those redundant init code blocks. With fire. :P

Comment: Oops, apparently `initWithData:` is already being used by other objects and the compiler is complaining about `[self alloc] initWithData:` I guess I'll just rename it to something else

Comment: I'd have gone with something like `initWithProperties:`/`carWithProperties:` (or `…WithDict:`) or the like anyway as `…WithData:` would make me expect it to ask for `NSData` objects, not `NSDictionary`.

Answer (score 0):

You would not define the methods with different signatures like:

```
+ (Car *)carWithData:(NSDictionary *)carData;
+ (Lexus *)carWithData:(NSDictionary *)carData;
```

you should instead use

```
+ (id)carWithData:(NSDictionary *)carData;
```

The implementation of the subclass would then look like

```
- (id)initWithData:(NSDictionary *)carData;
{
    self = [super initWithData:carData];
    if (self) {
         _navigation = [carData valueForKey:@"navigation"];
    }
    return self;
}

+ (id)carWithData:(NSDictionary *)carData;
{
    return [[[self alloc] initWithCarData:carData] autorelease];
}
```

Comment: If `Lexus` is a subclass of `Car`, you can redefine the declaration of the header to look like what you want.

Comment: Yes you can (I thought it would at least cause a warning, but it doesn't seem to) but that sounds like bad form as you have repeated code that changes only ever so slightly.

Answer (score 0):

Here would be my solution:

```
// interface
-(id) initWithCarData:(NSDictionary *) carData;
+(Car *) carWithCarData:(NSDictionary *) carData;

// car implementation
-(id) initWithCarData:(NSDictionary *) carData
{
    if (self = [super init])
    {
          // initialize car data
    }

    return self;
}

+(Car *) carWithCarData:(NSDictionary *) carData
{
    // note that 'self' here is the current class, 
    // there is no need to overwrite this method in the subclass
    return [[self alloc] initWithCarData:carData];
}

// lexus implementation
-(id) initWithCarData:(NSDictionary *) carData
{
     // initialize the variables that the superclass recognizes
     if (self = [super initWithCarData:carData])
     {
         // initialize the lexus data
     }

     return self;
}
```

So, when you call `[Lexus carWithCarData:myData]` it ends up calling the `Lexus`'s `init` method, not the `Car`'s.

Comment: You should never specify class return type in `initWith…:/fooWith…:`  (such as `Car *`), but always return `id` instead.

Answer (score 0):

There's another way, which is more generic, by using the `NSCoding` protocol and `NSKeyedArchiver`.

If the object you want to copy into a subclass of yours implements the `NSCoding` protocol, which is the case for many NS... based classes, the following totally legal and safe trick can be used:

```
// Assumptions:
// copyFrom is an object of ClassA
// We have a ClassB that is a subclass of ClassA
NSMutableData *data = [NSMutableData data];
NSKeyedArchiver *arch = [[NSKeyedArchiver alloc] initForWritingWithMutableData:data];
[copyFrom encodeWithCoder:arch]; // this archives its properties
[arch finishEncoding];
NSKeyedUnarchiver *ua = [[NSKeyedUnarchiver alloc] initForReadingWithData:data];
ClassB *ourCopy = [[ClassB alloc] initWithCoder:ua]; // this restores the properties into our new object
```